# DBIx::Class Temporary column

Tags: mysql, perl, catalyst, temporary, dbix-class

I am using [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class) and I have a query like this:

```
$groups = $c->model('DB::Project')->search(
{ "sessions.user_id"=>$c->user->id,done_yn=>'y' },
{
    select   => ["name", "id",\'SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)) as total_time'], #\''
    join         => 'sessions',
  }
);
```

I'd like to be able to get the value of `SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time))`, but because this is not a real column in the table, referencing total_time for a [DBIx::Class::Row](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::Row) object doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how I can get these temporary columns? Thanks!

Comment: I know what you mean. There are upsides and downside, but I feel like I'm comfortable enough with SQL that this doesn't really help too much. It's just that I'm writing a catalyst app and so many things are integrated with `DBIx::Class` that I basically feel like I have to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [select docs](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aResultSet#select) describe perfectly how to achieve what you're trying to accomplish.
It's also recommended to avoid literal SQL when possible, you can use `{ sum => \'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)' }` instead.
The 'as' in the literal SQL isn't required to give the column a name, you have to use either the as search attribute or better the columns shortcut instead of select+as.